# Why these objects aren't in right order?

Tags: html, css

My problem is with HTML and CSS. I feel that this topic is very confusing and this thinking are disappointing me from creating my idea in web. This is simply what I want to create; I draw it in paint just now.

[image: What I want my site to look like]

This is my HTML code for my own project first page:

```
<?php 
include("includes/classes/mysession.php");
mysession::start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/style_mainpage.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<div id="loginpart">
<form action="pages/userspage/checkuser.php" method="post" name="form_login" id="form_login">
<input name="txf_id" type="text" id="textfield_id"/>
<input name="txf_pw" type="password" id="textfield_pw"/>
<input name="button_login" type="submit" value="login" id="button_login" />
</form>
<a href="pages/signuppage/signup.php">sign up</a>
</div>

</div>
<hr />
<div id="content">
<div id="logopart">
     <img src="../../includes/images/logo.jpg" alt="AnaDilim" name="logoimg" id="logoimg" />
</div>
<div id="mainpart">
    <div id="searchbox">
        <form id="form_search "action="../../mainpage/index.php" method="get">
      <input id="textfield_search" name="textfield_search" type="text" maxlength="100" />
      <input id="button_search" name="button_search" type="submit" value="search" />
          </form>
     </div>
    <div id="resultpart">this is result part</div>
    <div id="numberpart">words:256000</div>
 </div>
 </div>
<hr />
<div id="footer">All rights reserved !!</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

this is my css:

```
/* CSS Document */
#container{
width: 100%;
background-color: #666;
/**********************
***********************
header part css
***********************
**********************/
}
#header {
width: 100%;
min-height: 50px;
background-color: #0FF;
}
#form_login {
float: left;
margin-left: 50px;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color: #F30;
margin-top: 15px;
min-width: 30%;
}
#txf_username {
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
}
#txf_password {
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
}
#button_login {
float: left;
margin-left: 20px;
min-width: 100px;
}
/*********************
**********************
end of header part
**********************
**********************/
#content{
width: 100%;
background-color: #FF0;
    }
#logopart {
width: 100%;
background-color: #0F0;
display: inline-block;
}

#logoimg{
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
display: block;
}
#mainpart {
width: 100%;
background-color: #39F;
display: inline-block;
}


#searchbox {
margin-top: 10px;
display: block;
background-color: #F00;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 50%;
}
#textfield_search {
vertical-align: middle;
width: 60%;
font-size: 24px;
}

#button_search {
vertical-align: middle;
width: 30%;
margin-left: 4%;
}
#resultpart {
background-color: #0FF;
width: 70%;
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
}
#numberpart {
background-color: #C6F;
display: block;
margin-top: 80px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 25%;
margin-bottom: 60px;
text-align: center;
clear: both;
}
#footer {
width: 100%;
background-color: #0CC;
text-align: center;
clear: both;
}
```

and this is my disappointing result:

[image]

In this page I paint dives with different colors to see how they works! Please say how I can design web sites easier without using HTML?

Comment: Your English seems fine to me, but please don't post all in lower case. When sentences start with upper-case characters, it is so much more readable.

Comment: It's not really the HTML that is your problem here, it is mostly your CSS, it's too messy for anyone to easily fix, I think you need to look up how to position elements properly, I noticed you used the 'float' property quite alot, which isn't very ideal, as for example you have applied it to your submit button on your login form, and it's resulted in floating it to the left of your input fields.

Comment: You cannot avoid html if you want to program for the web. You can make your life easier with a decent framework like bootstrap or foundation, but you will still need to learn html and css. Just be thankfull you will probably never have the fun of supporting IE > 9

Comment: @halfer : I'm sorry for posting in lower case,i will use upper-case chars for sentences starts!thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, it's as incredibly easy as this:

```
#loginpart input{float:left}
```

but it's strange since you have each element floated to the left, and then in your picture they're floated to the right, so try this:

1) kill all the floats
2) see what happens and if needed, add this (you won't need it, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koqk3cnt/) but for future reference):

```
#loginpart{display:block}
#loginpart input{display:inline-block}
```

then you may want to add specific CSS for each element (which you have correctly identified). If this doesn't work, then you have something else causing this

Comment: Because i am begginer in css i am program like a blind person i use every thing that i see in css attributes!!!!You are right i should delete all floats an use them if i need them,this will repair many problems.thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK. You are in a mess. So. Lets start afresh!

First off goto

http://www.getbootstrap.com

That is what a lot of us use to build the basics of our sites, learn bootstrap and things will look a lot neater and professional,and you need a lot less lines of css!

I'm a pro but not a magician, this is simple took me 5 mins. take a look and work on it.

I have not done it all for you

**Working fiddle: demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/301/

**HTML**

```
<!-- /lesson one: use bootsrap - getbootstrap.com --> 


<!-- /navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
</nav>
 <!-- /main box logo and search -->            
<div class="content">
    <img src="http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/about/firebird-logo-200.png"> <span class="input-group search">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>

</div>

        <!-- /results -->
<div class="results">Your search results go here</div>


 <!-- /below here goes a sticky footer - see bootstrap -->
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    margin-top:100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.search {
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.results {
    height: 200px;
    margin:50px 100px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I know this does not use your work, but I think your problem is you need some guidance on how we all do it, use a CSS framework lay it our neatly. I hope this is positive for you.

Comment: Thanks,your work is great!It is totally clear code,simple design and very beautiful!With seeing your work i fall in love with web design again:D.I think i can recognize code types and i am sure you are certainly professional(even a bit like magician!)

Comment: Thank's I was a bit worried my, start from scratch might be taken wrongly. Study bootstrap it was made by the folks at twitter and it has changed web-design over the last few years. Makes a few lines of HTML and CSS look decent.